# Retrieving list of TFS collections and projects

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, tfs

I am trying to get the list of projects under every collection from my TFS server and I don't find any easy way for this. Found a poweshell script but that needs V3 installed while I have only PS V2 and its taking a long time for version upgrade. Is there any other way to get the list of collections and projects from TFS? TIA!

Comment: what version of TFS is this for? I see you have tfs2010 tagged?

Comment: I am using 2015

Comment: If you are not restricted, you can even use excel to import the required data from TFS

Answer (score 0):

You can use this C# sample to get a list:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsConfigurationServer tfsc = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://{server_name}:8080/tfs"));
            tfsc.EnsureAuthenticated();

            var collectionNodes = tfsc.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
                new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
                false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

            foreach(CatalogNode collection in collectionNodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Collection {0} contains projects:", collection.Resource.DisplayName);
                var tpc = tfsc.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Guid(collection.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]));

                var projectNodes = tpc.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
                new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject },
                false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

                foreach (CatalogNode project in projectNodes)
                    Console.WriteLine(project.Resource.DisplayName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

References to libs in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer":

1. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
2. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll

Or you can try [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)